# How to include functionality from one project into another in the same solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-project

In my company, we are creating C# client/server applications as follows:
We create three project inside one single Visual Studio solution:

- Product.General
- Product.Client
- Product.Server

The "General" project contains functionality, to be used by both client and server parts.

In order to make this work, we compile the "Product.General" and add the binary as a reference to the "Product.Client" and "Product.Server" projects.

In our source code, this looks as follows:

In the "General" project:

```
namespace Product.Customer.Configuration
{
    public class SettingManager
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the "Server" project:

```
using Product.Customer.Configuration;
...
var settingManager = ...<SettingManager>();
```

I don't like, because amongst other first you need to get the "General" part compiled before you can even start working on your "Client" or "Server" project.

How can I get such a system to work, without needing to add compiled binaries into projects' references?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the reference with Add Project Reference and then select the General Project like this. and whenever you are making changes just do Ctrl+Shift+B to build the solution.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Visual Studio, right click on the `References` menu in the `Product.Client` or `Product.Server` project, click `Add Reference` in the popup select the `Projects` tab and then add a checkmark where needed (in your case `Product.General`) (see [vivek nuna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786593/9363973)). I assume it's basically the same in something liked Rider.

If you're not using Visual Studio, but are using the new .NET (**not** .NET Framework) you can use the [`dotnet` cli tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/) like so

```
dotnet add path/to/Product.Client.csproj reference path/to/Product.General.csproj
```

If the working directory of the shell your using contains a .csproj file, you can omit the first `path/to/*.csproj`, so doing something like this should work

```
cd Product.Client
dotnet add ../Product.General/Product.General.csproj
```

If you're not using Visual Studio or some other IDE and for some reason can't use the dotnet cli tool, then you can manually edit the .csproj files, like so

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="path/to/Product.General.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```